# Trying to create tag request in Atlassian Bitbucket using curl REST API

Tags: curl, bitbucket-server

I want to create a tag for a specific branch, but I have the following error:

{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class com.atlassian.stash.internal.rest.repository.RestCreateTagRequest, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method","exceptionName":"org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException"}]}== Info: Closing connection 0
== Info: schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with code.waters.com port 443

I using this curl command for posting the tag:

```
curl -X POST -u <<USER>>:<<PASSWORD>> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v --trace - -d """{"name":"TAG_CURL_TEST_01","target":{"hash":"dd0ad6f53a9ca318b1441ed1XXXXXXXX"}}""" https://HOSTNAME/bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/{project-id}/repos/{repo-id}/tags
```

Json:

> size  25 limit    25 isLastPage   false values     0
> id    "refs/tags/NG930_WSM210_20220712_B15"
> displayId "NG930_WSM210_20220712_B15" type    "TAG"
> latestCommit  "c85f121e9841489949baa789a2090c37c2826485"
> latestChangeset   "c85f121e9841489949baa789a2090c37c2826485"
> hash  "2fef60e14fa60462e00673150b658cf6b910a841"

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
"target":{"hash":"dd0ad6f53a9ca318b1441ed1XXXXXXXX"}}"
```

with:

```
"startPoint": "dd0ad6f53a9ca318b1441ed1XXXXXXXX"
```

To make it a bit easier to format you could create a file called tag.json, and add the following:

```
{
  "name": "TAG_CURL_TEST_01",
  "startPoint": "dd0ad6f53a9ca318b1441ed1XXXXXXXX"
}
```

Then change the `-d` parameter to `-d @tag.json` in your curl command.

Comment: Thanks a lot @eeijlar but I have the same error.